# PDO Login get Username

Tags: php, session, authentication, pdo

How do i echo out the Username when they got access to Admin.php? I've tried to like include the files and made others sessions and such but it doesn't work.
User.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once("anslutning.php");


class User{

    private $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Anslutning();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();

        }
    public function Login($username, $password){
        if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users where username =? and password=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $username);
            $st->bindParam(2, $password);
            $st->execute();

            if($st->rowCount() == 1) {
                header("Location: admin.php");
                $_SESSION['inloggad']="true";

                }else {
                    echo "Fel Användarnamn eller Lösenord!";
                    }


            }else {
                echo "Var vänlig och skriv in ett Användarnamn och Lösenord!";
                }



        }





    }



?>
```

Admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['inloggad']!="true") {
    header ("Location: loggain.php");
    }
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <?php include "../include/head.php" ?>
    <title>Swebby | Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="loggaut.php">Logga UT</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So my question is.. How do i make it echo out the username on the Admin,php? Thanks!!

Comment: where are you creating an object of the User class?

Comment: I think you need to include/require User.php on Admin.php, create an object of the User class and then call the function from the User class to display the information that you need to display.

Comment: I'm not, the two files is them i got. every code i wrote is there. I just followed an tutorial an added some extras

Comment: I'm new to PDO and such. Can u help me what to write? <3

Comment: see if this tutorial on objects/class is of any help:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762

Comment: + when i tri to include User.php it says it can't run 2 sessions and gives me an error ;(

Comment: try replacing session_start() with if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}

Comment: On wich site, Admin or User + Thanks for the link! I understand but wich one should i replace? <3

Comment: I think if you just need to display the username, then you need to set it first in the $_SESSION in Login and then just echo $_SESSION['Username'] on Admin.php.

Comment: nAH I MEAN LET'S DO IT THE WAY U SAID. iT GETS BETTER AND MORE "NEW" WICH OF THE SESSIONS I NEEDED TO !ISSET? caps***

Comment: I think I added all that I knew in the comments. You need to try making changes with the information provided and see if that works or no.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to look at.

1. Place this `$row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` underneath `$st->execute();`
2. Create a session for your username when the user logs in.
   Place `$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];` underneath `$_SESSION['inloggad']="true";`
   This assumes "username" is the name of the username field in your database

Then you can echo the username like this `<?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>`